# Div scrolling in the opposite direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a page whose entire content is wrapped inside a div – `<div id="wrapper"></div>` This div gets applied the property `transform: scale(1.3)` at 1600px & above.

Inside this wrapper, I have two divs side by side with their parent div set to `display: flex`

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="sidebar"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

On scrolling the content, the sidebar is supposed to stick to the top and not scroll. It does so but only when the `transform` property isn’t applied. Once the `transform` property gets applied to the wrapper, the sidebar starts scrolling in the opposite direction.

Here is link to the demo – http://cpll.co/happicities/the-happicity-model/

Set the width of your browser’s viewport to at least 1600px and you will notice this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. This may solve your problem

```css
#thm-container #thm-container-main {
    align-items: flex-start;
}
```

Comment: It does stop the scrolling but it doesn’t stick the sidebar to the top like it does in the unscaled version

Comment: Too many flex property written in your code. I think that's why 'position: sticky' is not working properly. But i'm not sure about it.